# How Can I Plot the Phase-Frequency Curve Using Mathematica?

Tags: differential-equations

I am trying to plot a phase angle vs. frequency curve numerically for the steady state condition of the following equation

```
x''[t] + 2 ζ x'[t] + x[t] == Cos[w t]
```

where `w` is the forcing frequency, and the initial conditions are `x[0] == 0, x'[0] == 0`. A similar plot is shown here:

[image: sample-plot]

Comment: Basically you want a Bode plot, right?

Answer (score 10):

**Method 1 : Using Bode Plot from signals and systems**

One more direct solution can be by making use of Mathematica's inbuilt `BodePlot`. You just need to find the Transfer function, which can be easily found in your equation by taking the Laplace Transform on both sides of the equation and is given as:

```
H[s_] := 1/(s^2 + 2 \[Zeta]  s + 1)
```

Now, use the `BodePlot` function, just for Phase by this code:

```
BodePlot[1/(s^2 + 2 (#)  s + 1) & /@ {0.005, 0.1, 0.38, 1}, 
 PlotLayout -> "Phase", 
 PlotLegends -> 
  Placed[LineLegend[{0.005, 0.1, 0.38, 1}, LegendLabel -> "\[Zeta]", 
    LegendFunction -> (Framed[#, RoundingRadius -> 5] &), 
    LegendMargins -> 3], {0.8, 0.7}]]
```

Which gives you a similar answer as given by @Nasser. You just need to change your units to the ones described in the reference.

[image: bode-plot]

**Method 2: Using Direct formula from the theory of vibrations**

You can easily find the theory of forced harmonic vibrations in any of the books on mechanical vibrations, like [Theory of Vibration with Applications by William Thomson](https://doi.org/10.1201/9780203718841) and [Theory of Vibration, An Introduction by Ahmed A. Shabana](https://doi.org/10.1007/978-3-319-94271-1), which directly provides you with the formula for phase angle ($\psi$) in terms of damping factor ($\zeta$) and frequency ratio ($r$) as:

$$ \psi = \tan^{-1} \bigg( \frac{2 r \zeta}{1-r^2} \bigg) $$

Then it's really easy to plot the phase-frequency curve:

```
\[Psi][\[Zeta]_, r_] := ArcTan[1 - r^2, 2  r  \[Zeta]];

Plot[Evaluate@
  Table[\[Psi][\[Zeta], r], {\[Zeta], {0.005, 0.1, 0.38, 1}}], {r, 0, 
  4}, PlotRange -> {{0, 3}, {0, 3.5}}, AspectRatio -> 1/GoldenRatio, 
 PlotPoints -> 1000, PlotTheme -> {"Scientific", "NeonColor"}, 
 FrameLabel -> {"Frequency ratio \[Rule]", "Phase angle \[Rule]"}, 
 LabelStyle -> {Black, Bold, 15}, 
 PlotLegends -> 
  Placed[SwatchLegend[Automatic, {0.005, 0.1, 0.38, 1}, 
    LegendMarkers -> "Bubble", LegendMarkerSize -> 20, 
    LegendFunction -> (Framed[#, RoundingRadius -> 10, 
        Background -> GrayLevel[0.85]] &), 
    LegendLabel -> "\[Zeta]"], {0.9, 0.25}], ImageSize -> Large]
```

which gives you the desired plot:

[image: phase-frequency]

Comment: Thankyou for your timely response. If the differential equation is highly nonlinear and  it is not possible to take Laplace transform for the differential equation, in that case what can I do or is there any alternative for the same?

Comment: @Abhishek can you provide me an example for such an equation related to your work? I will try to figure out a way.

Comment: Sure. Here is the equation:    `x''[T] == (1/\[Epsilon])*((((1 + WE)*(1 + \[Epsilon]*x[T])^(-3*\[Kappa] -1))) - ((1 + \[Epsilon]* x[T])^-1) - (WE*(1 + \[Epsilon]*x[T])^-2) - (4*damping*\[Epsilon]^2*(x'[T])*(1 + (\[Epsilon]* x[T]))^-2) - ((3*\[Epsilon]^2*(x'[T]^2)*(1 + \[Epsilon]*x[T])^-1)/2) - \[Epsilon]^3*f*Sin[T* (w0 + \[Epsilon]^2 w)])` with the initial conditions `x[0]=1, x'[0]=0`

Comment: and the values of the constants are `WE=0.2`, `\[Kappa]=1.4`, `\[Epsilon]=0.1`, and `damping=0.03`

Comment: @Abhishek, what is `f` and `w0` in your equation?

Comment: Sorry I forgot to mention that. `f=0.2` and `w0=2.05`

Comment: Although the Laplace transform only works for linear time-invariant systems, still nonlinear equations can be worked out by linearizing. Do you wish for a full nonlinear solution or a linearized one?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/151419/discussion-between-abhishek-and-codebpr).

Comment: @Abhishek, Transfer function is used in frequency domain analysis and that for linear systems only. You can't have it for any nonlinear system unless you linearize it around some point. Nonlinear systems can be chaotic as well and there is no analytic method to solve them. I suggest you post a new question, where you discuss the details of your problem, what have you tried so far and what do you expect as the result, along with related links of your equations on bubble oscillations. Experts on non-linear can then definitely answer that. If you are satisfied, don't forget to accept the answer.

Answer (score 7):

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Code

```
phase[r_, z_] := Module[{t}, t = ArcTan[(2 z  r)/(1 - r^2)];
   If[t < 0, t = t + Pi];
   180/Pi  t];
plotOneZeta[z_, f_] := Module[{r, p1, p2},
   p1 = Plot[f[r, z], {r, 0, 3}, PlotRange -> All, 
     PlotStyle -> Blue];
   p2 = Graphics[Text[z, {1.1, f[1.1, z]}]];
   Show[{p1, p2}]];
p = Map[plotOneZeta[#, phase] &, {.005, 0.1, 0.38, 1}];
Show[p, FrameLabel -> {{"Phase in degrees", 
    None}, {"r= ω/ωn", 
    "Phase vs. Frequency ratio for different ξ"}}, Frame -> True, 
 GridLines -> Automatic, GridLinesStyle -> Dashed, ImageSize -> 400, 
 AspectRatio -> 1]
```

Use degree for phase not radians. You can easily change that.

ps. I stole the code from this [page](https://12000.org/my_notes/mma_matlab_control/indexsection37.htm)

Comment: Thanks for the response. Is there any direct method to obtain the same plot for highly nonlinear differential equation?